Issues with test class receiving an Internal Salesforce error with Change Data Capture Trigger on ProcessInstanceStep
The below test passes, but I'm receiving Salesforce Internal Error, which is preventing coverage on the trigger and trigger handler class. I tested the functionality outside of the test class and everything works as expected. Thanks.
@isTest
static void testProcessWorkItemRequest() {
    Id processInstanceWorkitemId = [SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem LIMIT 1].Id;
    Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest request = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
    request.setComments('Test rejection.');
    request.setAction('Reject');
    request.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{ UserInfo.getUserId() });
    request.setWorkitemId(processInstanceWorkitemId);
    Test.enableChangeDataCapture();
    Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(request);
    Test.getEventBus().deliver();
}


This error was due to trigger framework we were using. There must have been a conflict. Once I ran the automation within the trigger itself the issues was resolved.
